# Android have user draw a scaling circle

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-drawable

I'm trying to make a basic "Paint"-esque app for a class, and part of what I'm trying to implement is the ability to draw a circle that scales in size as the user moves their finger to pick the center, and drags it outward to the desired radius. The problem is, no matter what I try it just ends up repeatedly stamping a small circle where ever the user moves their finger. The idea is the app will get the coordinates for the center (tX, tY) on the press down, draw a circle with a radius r every time the user moves, then finalize it when they lift their finger.

Edit: the commented out sections are parts where I was testing different things.

Code for my onMotionEvent custom class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //detect user touch     
    float tX = event.getX();
    float tY = event.getY();
    float rX = 0;
    float rY = 0;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(tX, tY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(shapes){
            rX = (int) event.getX();
            rY = (int) event.getY();

            r =  (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tX - rX, 2) + Math.pow(tY - rY, 2));

            drawCanvas.drawCircle(tX, tY, r, drawPaint);

            invalidate();
        }else{
            drawPath.lineTo(tX, tY);
        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        /*rX = event.getX();
        rY = event.getY();

        r =  (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tX - rX, 2) + Math.pow(tY - rY, 2));*/

        if(shapes){
            if(shape_sel == 0){
                //drawCanvas.drawCircle(tX, tY, r, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
            /*}else if(shape_sel == 1){

            }
            else{

            */}
        }else{
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
        }

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't saving tx and ty on touch down, you're resetting them on every event.  You need to save tx and ty in class level variables inside the down case.

Comment: I'd upvote you, but I'm too new. That did solve my problem however, thank you! If you want to help again, it works now, but the user can only increase the size of the circle, not decrease it. Thoughts?